# ionic serve Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined (CLI v2.1.7)

Tags: ionic-framework, macos-sierra

New project just installed by ionic (following instructions on ionic's site)  on macOs Sierra. When I try to run `ionic serve` it fails with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at Object.runr (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:191:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/cli.js:54:9
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)


Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined (CLI v2.1.7)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.11 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v4.2.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled ionic but still getting same error.
I was not getting any issues when using OS-X 10.9.

Comment: Same here. It was working, then I did a `npm install -g ionic` and it stopped; Maybe we should be using the 1.2.4 version (which is stable at npm).

Do `npm install -g ionic@1.2.4`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ionic (CLI) 2.1.7 seems to be unstable.
Try reinstalling ionic 2.0.0:

```
 npm uninstall -g ionic

 npm install -g ionic@2.0.0
```

Comment: As @Victor Nascimento suggested, the 1.2.4 of ionic is stable as well

Comment: Yes I did have to use ionic 2.0.0 and also had to use Cordova 6.0.0 before the error messages dwindled to a handful and the ionic serve command worked. @veljkoz 1.2.4 gave me lots of errors too, only 2.0.0 worked.

Comment: Indeed, who broke the build!?  I ran into this simply following the instructions on the getting started page for ionic.

Answer (score 3):

npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g ionic@2.1.8

2.1.8 FIX IT!

see https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/commit/3fde646

Answer (score 3):

As of ionic version 2.2.X the issue still exists if you try to serve an old app. Solution: create a file package.json with an empty object - { }, and place it in the root folder (by side of the www folder).

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling `ionic` and `cordova` and installing it separate. First cordova, then ionic. Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the /ionic/lib/cli.js file, around line 150 or so, there is a line that goes 
if(npmScripts.hasOwnProperty(...))

Change that to 
if(npmScripts && (npmScripts.hasOwnProperty(...))){

that should resolve this problem.  It did for me.